# Plotting heat equation in a Manipulate expression

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I have a 2D heat equation $u_t = \alpha (u_{xx} + u_{yy})$ with conditions:

- $u(x, y, 0) = 300$,
- $u_y(x, 0, t) = \mu_1(x)$,
- $u_y(x, 1, t) = \mu_2(x)$,
- $u(0, y, t) = \mu_3(y)$,
- $u(1, y, t) = \mu_4(y)$,

where:

- $\mu_1(x) = c_1$ if $|x - 0.5| < 0.25,$ else $0$,
- $\mu_2(x) = c_2$ if $|x - 0.5| < 0.25,$ else $0$.
- $\mu_3(y) = \mu_4(y) = T_0$

I am trying to solve it with the code, given below:

```
c1 = 100.0; c2 = -500.0; T0 = 500;

a = 0.002;

phi[x_, y_] = 300;

mu1[x_] := If[Abs[x - 0.5] <= 0.25, c1, 0];
mu2[x_] := If[Abs[x - 0.5] <= 0.25, c2, 0];

mu3[y_] := T0;
mu4[y_] := T0;

Off[NDSolve::ibcinc];

Manipulate[
  Module[{plt, sol},
    sol = NDSolve[
      { 
        D[u[x, y, t], t] == a (D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]),
        u[x, y, 0] == phi[x, y],
        (D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 0) == mu1[x],
        (D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 1) == mu2[x],
        u[0, y, t] == mu3[y],
        u[1, y, t] == mu4[y]
      },
      u[x, y, t], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 100}];
   plt = ContourPlot[
      u[x, y, t] /. sol /. t -> time, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
      Contours -> 15, 
      ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
      PlotLabel -> "Temperature profile", 
      ContourLabels -> True, 
      ImageSize -> Large]
  ],
  {{time, 5, "Time (t)"}, 5, 100, 0.5}
]
```

The problem is that I set $c_1, c_2$ to different values (even functions of $x$) but I can't see any difference on the plot. I think I should see some effect. If my code is incorrect, how do I fix it?

Comment: Why did you silence the error message?
u[0, 0, 0] = phy[0,0] = 300 != u[0, 0, 0] = mu3[y] = 500

Comment: If I set $T_0 = 300$, I will get plot full of anomalies and even singularities. But even if I do so (and get equally red plot), why doesn't heat flow affect the solution?

Comment: I am not sure what `NDSolve` is returning as a solution with those conflicting boundary conditions. Did you come up with the numbers yourself? Otherwise, where do they come from?

Comment: It is one of many options. Actually I am going to find analytical solution of this for any $c_1, c_2, T_0$.
But also I need visualization of it for some non-trivial $c_1, c_2, T_0$. But even if I remove inconsistency by considering $T_0 = \mu_3 = \mu_4$, I still get the same results for any $c_1, c_2$. But actually the final solution depends on them.

Comment: Mixo123, I managed to find a complete answer for your question, see my update below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

Recently I revisited the [obscure tutorial for `"MethodOfLines"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1306392612) and figured out how to fix your problem i.e. make `NDSolve` use `(D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 0) == mu1[x]` and `(D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 1) == mu2[x]` for solving the equation rather than ignore them. What you need to do is:

**(1)** Add `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" ->{True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}` to `NDSolve`.

This manual option adjustment is necessary because `NDSolve` will automatically set `"ScaleFactor" -> 0` for non-Dirichlet boundary condition, when i.c. and b.c. are inconsistent, this will make the Neumann inconsistent b.c. that's not a function of `t` be completely ignored.

**(2)** Use `UnitStep` instead of `Piecewise` or `If` to define `mu1` and `mu2`.

It's probably a bug, luckily we have `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` and `PiecewiseExpand` so don't need to reconstruct the function by hand.

The following is the fixed code:

```
c1 = -200.0; c2 = -200.0;
T0 = 500;
a = 0.002;
phi[x_, y_] = 300;

mu1[x_] = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@If[Abs[x - 0.5] <= 0.25, c1, 0]
mu2[x_] = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@If[Abs[x - 0.5] <= 0.25, c2, 0]

mu3[y_] := T0;
mu4[y_] := T0;

sol = u /. First@
   NDSolve[{D[u[x, y, t], t] == a (D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]), 
     u[x, y, 0] == phi[x, y], (D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 0) == 
      mu1[x], (D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 1) == mu2[x], u[0, y, t] == mu3[y], 
     u[1, y, t] == mu4[y]}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 100}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" ->{True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}]

Manipulate[ContourPlot[sol[x, y, time], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Contours -> 15, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLabel -> "Temperature profile", 
  ContourLabels -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
 , {{time, 5, "Time (t)"}, 5, 100, 0.5}
 ]
```

[image]

Now `mu1` and `mu2` apparently plays roles in the solution.

---

## Original Answer

Well, this answer is quite incomplete because I can't fix the problem. I post this answer just to point out that the true reason for the changeless `sol` is the BCs `(D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 0) == mu1[x]` and `(D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 1) == mu2[x]` are largely ignored by `NDSolve`. If you try:

```
Clear["`*"]
T0 = 500; a = 0.002; phi[x_, y_] = 300;

(*   I changed your definitions for mu1[x] and mu2[x] a little 
   since it doesn't work at least for version 8. *)
mu1[x_] := Piecewise[{{c1, Abs[x - 0.5] <= 0.25}}]; 
mu2[x_] := Piecewise[{{c2, Abs[x - 0.5] <= 0.25}}]; 
mu3[y_] := T0; 
mu4[y_] := T0;

sol[c1_, c2_] := NDSolve[{D[u[x, y, t], t] == a (D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]), 
                          u[x, y, 0] == phi[x, y], 
                          (D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 0) == mu1[x], 
                          (D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 1) == mu2[x], 
                          u[0, y, t] == mu3[y], 
                          u[1, y, t] == mu4[y]}, 
                          u[x, y, t], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 100}];

Plot3D[Evaluate[D[u[x, y, t] /. sol[100, -500], y] /. y -> 1], 
       {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All] 
Plot3D[Evaluate[D[u[x, y, t] /. sol[100, -500], y] /. y -> 0], 
       {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

you'll see:

[image]

[image]

Apparently `mu1[x]` and `mu2[x]` are almostly (maybe essentially…) not used. You can try several other `c1` and `c2` or even take off the BCs for $y=0$ and $y=1$ to confirm.

I guess some changes for the `Method` will help but haven't succeeded until now… Look forward to someone who's more experienced in solving PDEs！

Answer (score 4):

I think that one of the main issues related to the perceived responsiveness of `Manipulate` is still missing and should be addressed in this thread.  Same as `SynchronousUpdating`, `TrackedSymbols` is an option which must be taken into account when using `Manipulate`.
In general, if you have a toy application for `Manipulate` you won't need any of the two options, however, the more complicated your application the more likely you will need to use these two options.
`TrackedSymbols` is to tell `Manipulate` when to trigger an update.  If you don't specify which symbols to track `Manipulate` may update much more often than what you would expect.  In general you may think of `Manipulate` as a *Mathematica* expression that is wrapped with `Dynamic` and that will thus reevaluate its contents whenever any symbols in the expression changes.  To avoid continuous and unexpected reevaluations use `TrackedSymbols` to specify which symbols shuld trigger an update and your `Manipulate` will most probably start behaving as you expect.

One more comment: the more complicated your application is the more probably `Manipulate` will start becoming a bad tool to address your problem.  In this case you should start considering using `DynamicModule` which is basically the underlying backbone of `Manipulate`.  I have worked extensively with `Dynamic` tools and widgets ([this screencasts shows a good example](http://youtu.be/RhYoWRT2yPk)) and I can tell that starting to use `DynamicModule` requires a fairly large amount of practice and study time.

Comment: Welcome to `Mathematica.SE`! I edited your post and improved formatting, this can be helpful [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Great to see you here, Ariel! Your expertise will surely be much appreciated in this community. Please don't be put off by certain differences in the cultures of M SE and e.g. MathGroup (as some of other MathGroup veterans alas were), this place is in fact much friendlier than it might look from some distance and on the first sight.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things about your `Manipulate` that stand out as possible sources of trouble.

1. The use of `Module` to localize variables within a `Manipulate` isn't a good idea. It is better to introduce an invisible control to create a  local variable. Also note that the variable `plt` isn't needed at all.
2. For complex computations such as you are carrying out, it is a good idea to use the `SynchronousUpdating -> False` option. I suspect that not having this option set to `False` is the main source of your problem.

Making the required changes to your code to correct these two problems produces a `Manipulate` in which the plot the dynamically changes when the `time` slider is moved.

```
Manipulate[
  sol = NDSolve[{
    D[u[x, y, t], t] == a (D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]), 
    u[x, y, 0] == phi[x, y], 
    (D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 0) == mu1[x], 
    (D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 1) == mu2[x], 
    u[0, y, t] == mu3[y], 
    u[1, y, t] == mu4[y]}, 
    u[x, y, t], 
    {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 100}];
  ContourPlot[u[x, y, t] /. sol /. t -> time, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
    Contours -> 15,
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
    PlotLabel -> "Temperature profile",
    ContourLabels -> True],
  {{time, 5, "Time (t)"}, 5, 100, 0.5},
  {sol, ControlType -> None},
  SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

Here is the plot a `t =5`.

[image: heat at 5]

Here is the plot a `t =30`.

[image: heat at 30]

Comment: Thank you for optimizations! I will definitely use them.
But the problem was in fixing incorrect results from NDSolve or understanding why are they correct.
I don't get why results are the same for any $c_1, c_2$: heat flow should somehow have an influence on solution.

Comment: @m_goldberg: why do you say that localizing variables with `Module` within a `Manipulate` isn't a good idea? I don't think that in general there is anything wrong with doing that. Especially I can't see how defining a hidden dynamic variable has any advantages over a `Module` local variable for this case. Why do you think it's better?

Comment: @AlbertRetey Well, for one thing, using module inside manipulate creates a lot of symbols. So I would use `Module` around manipulate. But in that case it's better to use `DynamicModule` as that would retain values between sessions. Compare for example `Manipulate[Module[{z}, {z, a}], {a, 0, 2}]` and `Module[{z}, Manipulate[{z, a}, {a, 0, 2}]]`;

Comment: @Ajasja: while it ist true that `Module` does create a lot of symbols for the local variables if used inside a `Manipulate` these usually are temporary and removed after the `Module` finishes (with the  usual exceptions as in your examples). A `Manipulate` inside a `Module` will, on the other hand, only generate symbols for the local variables once, but these will *always* leak if used in the `Manipulate` and remain existing -- which  I think is potentially a larger problem...

Comment: @Ajasja: ... here are two examples with a more appropriate usage of `Module` which show what I am trying to say: `Manipulate[Module[{z}, z = a^2; z], {a, 0, 2}]` vs. `Module[{y}, Manipulate[y = a^2; y, {a, 0, 2}]]`. Interestingly by checking with `Names["Global`*"]` I found that `Manipulate` itself does leave behind a mess of new symbols for its own local variables, which I honestly do consider a "dirty" job, especially considering that `DynamicModule` doesn't show the problem...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Well outside `Module` both `Manipulate[Module[{z}, z = a^2; z], {a, 0, 2}];z` and `Module[{y}, Manipulate[y = a^2; y, {a, 0, 2}]];y` work correctly. But I agree completely that Manipulate (and Module) do a dirty job of leaving temporary symbols in the namespace.