# Manipulate freezing on large calculations

Tags: manipulate

I have a sum that ordinarily takes some time (2 - 3 seconds) to calculate. When I put it into a manipulation though, it becomes very temperamental. It will work on some very small calculations, but completely refuses to output anything for larger values. Is this a characteristic of `Manipulate`, or is there some way to work around it? I looked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/why-do-buttons-with-choicedialog-freeze-the-front-end), but can't get it to work on `Manipulate`.

Comment: Have you tried the option `SynchronousUpdating -> False`?

Comment: Great - that fixed it :)

Comment: ...Mostly :/ - Still a bit temperamental though. Are there any other fixes?

Comment: No way of telling without seeing some code.

Comment: A similar question with the same answer can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24588/3066)