# Piecewise causes ndnum warning in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, finite-element-method, discontinuity

**Bug introduced in 5.0, persisting through 13.2.**

---

I try to solve the heat transfer equation with boundary condition that depends on time:

```
r0 = 0.75 10^-3;(*Beam spot size, m*)
ω = π ν;
ν = 1; (*pulse repetition rate, Hz*)

c = 1710;(*Heat capacity, W/(m·K)*)
ρ = 879; (*Density, kg/m^3*)
λ = 0.111;(*Heat conductivity, W/(m·K)*)
T0 = 300;(*initial temperature,K*)
T1 = 1000 - T0; (*Hot state temperature, K*)
Rm = 3 10^-3;(*Sample Radius, m*)
zm = 2 10^-3 ;(*Sample thickness, m*)   

 eq = D[T[R, z, t], t] == λ/(
    c ρ) (1/(R + 10^-20) D[R D[T[R, z, t], R], R] + 
      D[T[R, z, t], {z, 2}]);

init1 = T[R, z, 0] == T0;
bc1 = D[T[R, z, t], {R, 1}] == 0 /. R -> 0;
bc2 = D[T[R, z, t], {R, 1}] == 0 /. R -> Rm;
bc3 = T[R, z, t] == 
    Piecewise[{{T0 + T1 (1 - Abs@Sin[ω t])^500, 
       0 <= R <= r0}, {T0, True}}] /. z -> 0;
bc4 = T[R, z, t] == T0 /. z -> zm;

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, init1, bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4}, 
  T[R, z, t], {R, 0, Rm}, {z, 0, zm}, {t, 0, 10},
  AccuracyGoal -> 30, MaxStepFraction -> 0.05]
```

The piecewise function defines the temperature at the left side of the z-interval as a short square pulses coming with frequency `ω` to central part of the disk.

However, solver returns the error-messages:

> NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are
> inconsistent.
> NDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.

What's wrong? I've tried with FEM package but it produce even more error-messages :)

Comment: When `t=0`, `init` and `bc3` are inconsistent, it makes `T[R, 0, 0]` both `300` and `1000` for `0 <= R <= 0.00075`.

Comment: @Feyre, ok, let's add small shift to `t` at bc3 making (t-5*10^-3) instead of t inside Sin. Unfortunately, it does not change principally anything.

Comment: Why don't change `Sin` to `Cos` in `bc3`?

Comment: @MMM, Is it principal? :)

Comment: @Rom38 I don't know about that.

Comment: There're several issues here, including a possible bug. Before giving an answer, I want to ask: why does the `(1 - Abs@Sin[ω t])^500` term exist? Are you approximate `DiracDelta` with it? If so, then it's incorrect because these peaks don't integrate to `1`, if not, then this term can be simply taken away, because it'll almost have no effect in the solution.

Comment: The Sin is defining the time-profile of the pulse. It can be different but principally the solution should be available by the same method. At least I guess so :\

Comment: @xzczd, this term defines the periodical heat incomes at left boundary. I did not realize how to set the periodical peaks with `DiracDelta`. Do you have any ideas? The integration errors should lead to certain problems with convergence of the solution but in this case solver do not start at all..
Actually, these peaks can have any area from the common point - the heat incomes can has an arbitrary form.

Comment: I added a "bugs" tag to the question. Though the `ndnum` warning isn't the only issue behind OP's problem, I think it's good to have a question related to this bug tagged with "bugs", so future visitors can find it easier.

Answer (score 5):

Several issues here.

1. As mentioned by [Feyre](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7312/feyre), the i.c. and b.c. are inconsistent. I'll set `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}` in response. For more information check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871) post.
2. `ndnum` is caused by a bug of `NDSolve` (yeah it's confirmed, I reported it WRI before), similar problem has been observed in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24630/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128624/1871) post. This can be resolved by adding `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep@ `` before `Piecewise`.
3. The modeling for laser pulse is improper. Ideally `DiracDelta` is a possible choice, but currently `NDSolve` can't handle it properly, so we need to use an approximate one, for example:

   ```
   dirac[r_, a_] = Sqrt[a/Pi] Exp[-a r^2];
   ```

   Periodity can be achieved with `Mod`:

   ```
   Plot[dirac[Mod[t, 1, -1/2], 100], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's the solution:

```
(* Previous code is not modified so I'd like to omit them in this post. *)
dirac[r_, a_] = Sqrt[a/Pi] Exp[-a r^2];

bc3 = T[R, z, t] == Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
         Piecewise[{{T0 + T1*dirac[Mod[t, Pi/ω, -2^(-1)], 100], 
        0 <= R <= r0}, {T0, True}}] /. z -> 0;
bc4 = T[R, z, t] == T0 /. z -> zm;

mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
        "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
mol[tf : False | True, sf_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines",
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {tf, "ScaleFactor" -> sf}}

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, init1, bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4}, 
    T, {R, 0, Rm}, {z, 0, zm}, {t, 0, 10}, 
    Method -> Union[mol[60, 2], mol[True, 100]]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Animate[Plot3D[sol[r, z, t], {r, 0, Rm}, {z, 0, zm}, PlotRange -> {0, 4000}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

**Remark**

1. `NDSolve` spits out `eerr` warning, but I think it's not a big problem since the error is small. Use more grid points will probably suppress the error, you can have a try if you have time.
2. I think `"FiniteElement"` will do a better job on solving this problem.
3. I took away `AccuracyGoal` because of the reason mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm enough new in solution of DE in Mathematica..